# How can I simplify my code for easy maintainance

Tags: php

I have a long IF else statement that checks the url and display a button, Im struggling to simplify the code so that it will also be easier to maintain.I would prefer a loop to go through all tohse pages.

```
if(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit.php')){
        echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'index.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs managemen toolkit..
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'index.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'organising_delegating')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/organising_delegating.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/organising_delegating.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'problem_solving')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/problem_solving.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/problem_solving.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'exit_transition_onboard')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/exit_transition_onboard.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/exit_transition_onboard.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'recruitment_onboarding')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/recruitment_onboarding.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/recruitment_onboarding.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'manage')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/manage.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/manage.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'leadership')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/leadership.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/leadership.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'grow_develop_coach')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/grow_develop_coach.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/grow_develop_coach.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'reward_recognition')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/reward_recognition.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/reward_recognition.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'planning')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/planning.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}

elseif(($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/planning.php')){ //TODO : change the URLs
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
}elseif(($currentPageButton == 'communication')){ 
   echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .'management_toolkit/communication.php" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>'; //TODO : change the URLs for Leadership
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code basically repeat himself...

```
$irRelevantURL = "http://example.com/example/";
$length = stripos($currentUrl,irRelevantURL);
           +strlen(irRelevantURL);
$relevant = substr($currentUrl,$length);
echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME .$relevant'" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
```

And, you probably mean `$HOSTNAME`...

Answer (score -1):

Use switch statement for it:

```
switch($currentUrl) {    
 case 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/planning.php':
  $url = 'management_toolkit/planning.php';
  break;
 case 'http://example.com/example/management_toolkit/reward_recognition.php':
  $url = 'management_toolkit/reward_recognition.php';
  break;
 default : 
  $url = 'home.php';
  break;
}
 echo '<div class="prevbutton"><a href="'. HOSTNAME . $url . '" class="previousNavbutton"><span style="padding-left:5px;">Back</span></a></div>';
```